# What is the benefit of using std::copy instead of manual for loop to copy dynamic array?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, c++11, deep-copy

Suppose I have the following code:

```
int* intPtr = new int[5];

// ...do stuff...
```

And now I want to copy intPtr to a new, identical, array:

```
int* newIntPtr = new int[5];
```

This can be done using either a simple for-loop or std::copy():

1. Using a for loop

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       *(newIntPtr + i) = *(intPtr + i);
   ```
2. Using std::copy()

   ```
   std::copy( intPtr, intPtr + 5, newIntPtr );
   ```

Using std::copy(), I get a warning in Visual Studio:

```
warning C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe...
```

I **could** use `stdext::checked_array_iterator<int*>` to make the warning go away:

```
std::copy(intPtr, intPtr + 5, stdext::checked_array_iterator<int*>(newIntPtr, 5));
```

but that means the code won't compile on anything else than Visual Studio.

So, how should I solve this? Should I use the simple for loop and effectively avoid the warning, or should I use std::copy() and do something to avoid the warning? Obviously, I could disable the warning, but that doesn't seem like a proper solution... or is it?

Comment: How about using `std::vector` instead of the raw arrays?

Comment: This seems like a matter of opinion. My opinion is that these "security" warnings are one of the greatest nuisances ever built into MSVC, and that you should just define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1` to disable them rather than write less idiomatic code to avoid them (or even worse, less portable code). Replacing the raw array with `std::vector` also seems like a sane idea, mind you.

Comment: @Baum mit Augen Yes, I'd prefer that, but this is for a project where I specifically have to use a C array.

Comment: "doesn't seem like a proper solution" to whom how. C++ is inherently unsafe. `stdext::checked_array_iterator<int*>(newIntPtr, 5))` is just as unsafe as `newIntPtr` (how do you know there are really 5 elements)? The for loop is likewise unsafe. I view these Visual C++ warnings as a marketing ploy designed to push people towards proprietary Microsoft APIs.

Comment: The question should be, why write a manual for loop when there exists a library function? The warning you get is because you are not writing modern C++ code.

Comment: @n.m. `s/proprietary Microsoft API's/Annex K of the C standard since C99/`.

Comment: @rubenvb Annex K has nothing to do with C++ APIs like `std::copy` (and it's C11, not C99).

Comment: `std::copy_n(intPtr, 5, newIntPtr)` would be a bit more idiomatic than `std::copy(intPtr, intPtr + 5, newIntPtr)`. Even better would be to replace the arrays with `std::array<int, 5>`  and use plain copy assignment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few benefits for using `std::copy` over a loop:

1. The call is self-documenting. A reader of your call instantly knows what was the intent of the statement without having to read comments or figuring out what the loop is doing
2. It may be optimized for simple types as in you case :

> In practice, implementations of std::copy avoid multiple assignments and use bulk copy functions such as std::memmove if the value type is TriviallyCopyable
>   [source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

3. More maintainable. Your container is more easily replaceable in the future. You only need to change the parameters to copy and not implementation

As other comments have mentioned, both, the loop and copy calls are equally unsafe so the warning is misleading. However, I would avoid disabling security warnings for the whole application. Instead, disable locally with `#pragma disable`

Comment: The use of `memmove` would generally be a pessimization, even for trivially copiable types.

Comment: I tried #pragma warning(disable: 4996), and it seems to work when the code is in a cpp-file, but in my case it is in an inlined class member function in a header-file, and it doesn't seem to work there?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious advantage is that using `std::copy` says explicitly
what you are doing.  The reader doesn't have to analyse the loop to
figure it out.  A second advantage is that it is less lines of code.
This isn't an absolute advantage; sometime being a little more verbose
is better.  But when you use less lines of code to make the code
clearer, it's definitely an advantage.

For the rest: in theory, the compiler could have built-in knowledge of a
standard function, and apply optimizations that it wouldn't be able to
find for a user written function or a loop.  In practice, I don't know
of any compiler which does.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question concerning the potential benefits of `std::copy` et. al:

The benefits are that, supposedly, the library implementation may be more efficient than a plain loop (e.g. An intrinsic for POD types). For example, `memcpy` in plain C on x86 can be more readily optimized to a `rep movsb` for small sizes.

As for the warnings: If it does not make sense, it ought to be reported as a bug, then disabled/ignored.

In this case, a warning issued for a call made by the library code to its own implementation is nonsensical, and really warrants a bug report.

Comment: Actually, the compiler can usually optimize the plain loop better than `memcpy`; it may be able to determine that the pointers are aligned, and that the count is a multiple of some wider type, and so copy usiing this wider type.  This is particularly true if the copy is of `int`, for example.

Comment: Honestly, I can't say everyone would be happy with any answer here. I think a better explanation might have been "to more precisely convey intent," where someone else might argue "it helps keep code concise." Personally, I think these standardized micro-utilities are just committee-driven pedanticism (like the not-so-expressive `pair<>`).

Comment: "to more precisely convey intent" and "it helps to keep the code concise" are more or less what I said.  But there's some merit in your final comment.  In the case of `std::copy`, no---it's generally useful and with a good name.  Things like `pair` are more or less obfuscation.  (It's convenient for quicky code which won't have to be maintained.  But who uses C++ for that?)

Answer (score 0):

First of all use Copy instead of for loop which faster for huge data.On other hand the error that you are getting had it's own meaning, Warning reminds you that function parameter values may be wrong and may cause damage in future.i.e. Risk of buffer overflow. I would suggest you take the compiler's own advice and use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

Comment: It's not *necessarily* faster for any sizes of data.

Comment: @NeilKirk In all of the implementations I've seen, the compiler will generate pretty much the same code for `std::copy` and for a manually written loop.  The only thing which might make a difference is `std::memcpy` (which will be slower, unless the compiler treats it as a built-in).

Comment: @JamesKanze Correct? Same is not faster or slower.